# Programmatically create HTML form fieldset tag with JSF

Tags: html, forms, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, form-generator

In my Java code I want to programmatically create a `<fieldset>` tag that I can use in my JSF form.

The setup of my form looks like this:

```
Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();

HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) app.createComponent(HtmlForm.COMPONENT_TYPE);
form.setStyleClass("pure-form pure-form-stacked");
```

As you can see I use `HtmlForm.COMPONENT_TYPE` as an identifier for the JSF UI component but I haven't found an identifier for a fieldset so I tried:

```
UIComponent fieldset = app.createComponent("fieldset");
form.getChildren().add(fieldset);
```

Unfortunately this is not working so I have to come up with another solution. Do you have any ideas?

Is there a general approach how HTML tags (which are unknown in the JSF context) can be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

Theres a component called `<f:verbatim>` which you would use in xhtml like this:

```
<f:verbatim escape="false">
    <fieldset id="blah"></fieldset>
</f:verbatim>
```

To achieve that programmaticlly you can add this component like this:

```
String fieldsetHTMLText ="<fieldset id=\"blah\"></fieldset>";

UIOutput verbatim = new UIOutput();
verbatim.setRendererType("javax.faces.Text");
verbatim.getAttributes().put("escape", false);
verbatim.setValue(fieldsetHTMLText);
```

Answer (score 4):

I found three solutions to my problem. The first one is to use `PrimeFaces`, the second one is to use `MyFaces Tomahawk` and the third one is to use a `JSF Verbatim UI component` with string input. I will shortly list up code samples and the differences between the solutions.

## 1 PrimeFaces

With an include of the PrimeFaces components suite (and it's Apache Commons FileUpload dependency) one can use the Fieldset class to programatically create a fieldset on-the-fly. The bad thing on that is, that the PrimeFaces Fieldset component is depends on a PrimeFaces JavaScript file so instead of the plain fieldset, one will get a fieldset and a JavaScript include which is way too much.

```
import org.primefaces.component.fieldset.Fieldset;

...

form.getChildren().add(new Fieldset());
```

## 2 MyFaces Tomahawk

The UI component set Tomahawk also comes with a Fieldset component that can be used to create an HTML fieldset programatically. If the Fieldset of Tomahawk will be used, then one will get a plain and nice-looking fieldset tag. The bad thing here is that Tomahawk is an extension to MyFaces and MyFaces itself is a whole JavaServer Faces implementation which should not be used alongside standard JSF.

```
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fieldset.Fieldset

...

form.getChildren().add(new Fieldset());
```

## 3 JSF Verbatim UI Component

The standardized and hacky way is to use a JSF Verbatim UI component. Within a verbatim component you are allowed to put any HTML needed. With this little trick we can create a verbatim tag:

```
UIOutput fieldset = new UIOutput();
fieldset.setRendererType("javax.faces.Text");
fieldset.getAttributes().put("escape", false);
fieldset.setValue("<fieldset></fieldset>");
```

The code shown above renders a fieldset HTML element but because it is a string and the tag inside the string is closed you cannot programatically append anything to that tag, so this won't work:

```
form.getChildren().add(fieldset);
```

To generate an HTML tag that can be used for nesting of elements, each opening and closing tag must be put in an own Varbatim component which makes this solution very text heavy:

```
UIOutput fieldsetStart = new UIOutput();
fieldsetStart.setRendererType("javax.faces.Text");
fieldsetStart.getAttributes().put("escape", false);
fieldsetStart.setValue("<fieldset>");

UIOutput fieldsetClose = new UIOutput();
fieldsetClose.setRendererType("javax.faces.Text");
fieldsetClose.getAttributes().put("escape", false);
fieldsetClose.setValue("</fieldset>");

HtmlInputText inputText = (HtmlInputText) app.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);

form.getChildren().add(fieldsetStart);
form.getChildren().add(inputText);
form.getChildren().add(fieldsetClose);
```

**Conclusion:**

None of the solutions shown is really elegant. PrimeFaces und MyFaces have large dependencies and the standard JEE way requires practally much writing effort. I had hoped to find a nice solution to produce unknown / custom HTML elements, such as: `document.createElement("fieldset");`.

If anyone knows a way to do that, please post the solution.